Flowbite bug: why does this dropdown have to be clicked twice before edit modal appears?

This is the dropdown button
                    <td class="flex items-center justify-end px-4 py-3">
                      <button
                        :id="`${el.id}-dropdown-button`"
                        :data-dropdown-toggle="`${el.id}-dropdown`"
                        class="dark:hover-bg-gray-800 inline-flex items-center rounded-lg p-1.5 text-center text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-800 focus:outline-none dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-gray-100"
                        type="button"
                      >
                        <svg
                          class="h-5 w-5"
                          aria-hidden="true"
                          fill="currentColor"
                          viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        >
                          <path
                            d="M6 10a2 2 0 11-4 0 2 2 0 014 0zM12 10a2 2 0 11-4 0 2 2 0 014 0zM16 12a2 2 0 100-4 2 2 0 000 4z"
                          />
                        </svg>
                      </button>
                      <div
                        :id="`${el.id}-dropdown`"
                        class="z-10 hidden w-44 divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded bg-white shadow dark:divide-gray-600 dark:bg-gray-700"
                      >
                        <ul
                          class="py-1 text-sm"
                          :aria-labelledby="`${el.id}-dropdown-button`"
                        >
                          <li>
                            <button
                              @click="openModalEdit(el)"
                              :key="el.id"
                              type="button"
                              v-bind:data-modal-target="
                                contentToEdit ? modalEditId : undefined
                              "
                              v-bind:data-modal-toggle="
                                contentToEdit ? modalEditId : undefined
                              "
                              class="flex w-full items-center px-4 py-2 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:text-gray-200 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white"
                            >
                              <svg
                                class="mr-2 h-4 w-4"
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                                fill="currentColor"
                                aria-hidden="true"
                              >
                                <path
                                  d="M17.414 2.586a2 2 0 00-2.828 0L7 10.172V13h2.828l7.586-7.586a2 2 0 000-2.828z"
                                />
                                <path
                                  fill-rule="evenodd"
                                  clip-rule="evenodd"
                                  d="M2 6a2 2 0 012-2h4a1 1 0 010 2H4v10h10v-4a1 1 0 112 0v4a2 2 0 01-2 2H4a2 2 0 01-2-2V6z"
                                />
                              </svg>
                              {{ $t("Edit") }}
                            </button>
                          </li>

                          <li>
                            <button
                              @click="idToDelete = el.id"
                              type="button"
                              data-modal-target="deleteModal"
                              data-modal-toggle="deleteModal"
                              class="flex w-full items-center px-4 py-2 text-red-500 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-red-400"
                            >
                              <svg
                                class="mr-2 h-4 w-4"
                                viewBox="0 0 14 15"
                                fill="none"
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                aria-hidden="true"
                              >
                                <path
                                  fill-rule="evenodd"
                                  clip-rule="evenodd"
                                  fill="currentColor"
                                  d="M6.09922 0.300781C5.93212 0.30087 5.76835 0.347476 5.62625 0.435378C5.48414 0.523281 5.36931 0.649009 5.29462 0.798481L4.64302 2.10078H1.59922C1.36052 2.10078 1.13161 2.1956 0.962823 2.36439C0.79404 2.53317 0.699219 2.76209 0.699219 3.00078C0.699219 3.23948 0.79404 3.46839 0.962823 3.63718C1.13161 3.80596 1.36052 3.90078 1.59922 3.90078V12.9008C1.59922 13.3782 1.78886 13.836 2.12643 14.1736C2.46399 14.5111 2.92183 14.7008 3.39922 14.7008H10.5992C11.0766 14.7008 11.5344 14.5111 11.872 14.1736C12.2096 13.836 12.3992 13.3782 12.3992 12.9008V3.90078C12.6379 3.90078 12.8668 3.80596 13.0356 3.63718C13.2044 3.46839 13.2992 3.23948 13.2992 3.00078C13.2992 2.76209 13.2044 2.53317 13.0356 2.36439C12.8668 2.1956 12.6379 2.10078 12.3992 2.10078H9.35542L8.70382 0.798481C8.62913 0.649009 8.5143 0.523281 8.37219 0.435378C8.23009 0.347476 8.06631 0.30087 7.89922 0.300781H6.09922ZM4.29922 5.70078C4.29922 5.46209 4.39404 5.23317 4.56282 5.06439C4.73161 4.8956 4.96052 4.80078 5.19922 4.80078C5.43791 4.80078 5.66683 4.8956 5.83561 5.06439C6.0044 5.23317 6.09922 5.46209 6.09922 5.70078V11.1008C6.09922 11.3395 6.0044 11.5684 5.83561 11.7372C5.66683 11.906 5.43791 12.0008 5.19922 12.0008C4.96052 12.0008 4.73161 11.906 4.56282 11.7372C4.39404 11.5684 4.29922 11.3395 4.29922 11.1008V5.70078ZM8.79922 4.80078C8.56052 4.80078 8.33161 4.8956 8.16282 5.06439C7.99404 5.23317 7.89922 5.46209 7.89922 5.70078V11.1008C7.89922 11.3395 7.99404 11.5684 8.16282 11.7372C8.33161 11.906 8.56052 12.0008 8.79922 12.0008C9.03791 12.0008 9.26683 11.906 9.43561 11.7372C9.6044 11.5684 9.69922 11.3395 9.69922 11.1008V5.70078C9.69922 5.46209 9.6044 5.23317 9.43561 5.06439C9.26683 4.8956 9.03791 4.80078 8.79922 4.80078Z"
                                />
                              </svg>
                              {{ $t("Hapus") }}
                            </button>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </td>

And the edit modal is initiated like this
  <ModalCreateEdit
    v-if="contentToEdit"
    :key="contentToEdit.id"
    type="edit"
    :id="modalEditId"
    :content-to-edit="contentToEdit"
  />

with edit button triggering this part of the code
const contentToEdit = ref<Content>();

const openModalEdit = async (newContent: Content) => {
  contentToEdit.value = { ...newContent };
  await nextTick(); // Ensure the DOM is updated with the new value
};

I added await nextTick(); to make sure that it waits for the contentToEdit to have a value first before opening the modal but somehow the modal only opens after I click the second dropdown that appears.

What do you see in your devtools? Is there a duplicate in the DOM? Some CSS z-index issues or alike? Any errors in the console?

await nextTick can't affect anything if a promise that openModalEdit returns isn't chained anywhere (it's not, "click" doesn't care about it). The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , it's unknown how ModalCreateEdit is implemented, and the snippet for dropdown button lacks context. It's unclear why you have dupe dropdows. That you use data- attrs suggests they are required for non-vue modal lib which can mean the problem is that vue is incorrectly integrated with them, this is the primary concern when you do such a thing
